# Являются ли однокоренными слова КРАСОТА и УКРАШЕНИЯ в современном русском языке?

Tags: этимология, словообразование, однокоренные-слова

В словаре Тихонова указаны две основные группы слов с корнем -крас-:

- от *красота*
- от *краска*

Более детальное исследование показывает наличие общих предков в диахронии, но в современном языке, насколько я могу судить, это разные корни.

Вопрос: являются ли однокоренными слова *красота* и *украшения (сущ. в значении ювелирн. -//-)*?

Comment: _Более детальное исследование показывает наличие общих предков в диахронии, но **в современном языке, насколько я могу судить, это разные корни**._  === А на основании чего Вы можете так судить?

Answer (score 2):

Украшение - это буквально то, что делает "краше" (красивее). Слова родственные, но корень второго слова "краш" модифицирован отн. "крас" при образовании исходного прилагательного сравнительной степени "краше" (вариант от "красивее").